# Sed ignoring potential characters at the end of the match group

Tags: sed

I have the following text:

```
<h2 id="title">    ABC A BBBBB0    </h2>
<h2 id="title">ABC A BBBBB1 </h2>
<h2 id="title">ABC A BBBBB2</h2>
<h2 id="title"> ABC A BBBBB3 </h2>
```

and want to get of it the following:

```
ABC A BBBBB0
ABC A BBBBB1
ABC A BBBBB2
ABC A BBBBB3
```

I am currently running the next command:

`sed -n "s/.*\"title\">[[:space:]]*\(.*\)<.*/\1/p" ./file.txt`

but get lines with spaces at the end:

```
ABC A BBBBB0[space][space][space][space]
ABC A BBBBB1[space]
ABC A BBBBB2
ABC A BBBBB3[space]
```

I can not understand the concept of ignoring possible spaces at the end in my case, at the beginning of the possible matches I understand how to do it. Can somebody give me a clear example for this?

Comment: Just add another space pattern:`[[:space:]]*<`. Note that `sed` can not parse all valid html or xml correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The last character in the group has to not be a space, then there may be spaces.

```
's/.*"title">[[:space:]]*\(.*[^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]*<.*/\1/p'
```

> I can not understand the concept

`.*` matches *everything* up until the end of *the whole line*. Then regex engine reads `<` and *goes back* from right to left up until it matches `<`, and then continues matching further.

You have to put something so that when you *go back* from the end of the string, you will end up at the place you want to be. So "not a space", for example. The process of "going back" is called "backtracking".

I can recommend https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[^>]*>[[:space:]]*\?\([[:alnum:][:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]\?<.*/\1/' file
ABC A BBBBB0
ABC A BBBBB1
ABC A BBBBB2
ABC A BBBBB3
```

```
$ sed -E 's/[^>]*> *?([A-Z0-9 ]*) ?<.*/\1/' file
ABC A BBBBB0
ABC A BBBBB1
ABC A BBBBB2
ABC A BBBBB3
```

When using `sed`s grouping and back referencing, you can easily exclude any character, including spaces by not including it within the grouping parenthesis.

`[^>]*>` - Skip everything till the next `>`, as this is not within the parenthesis, it will be excluded.

`*?` - As too will this space. The `?` makes it an optional character (or zero or more).

`([A-Z0-9 ]*)` - Everything within the parenthesis is included which will be capitals, integers and spaces.

`?<.*/\1/'` - Exclude a single space before `<` if one is present.

Comment: `*?` is back-to-back repetition metachars and so is undefined behavior per POSIX. `X*?` translates to "X repeated zero-or-more times repeated zero-or-1 times" so even when you say it it's just meaningless as there's no string that could match that `X*` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use awk:

```
$ awk -F'> *| *<' '{print $3}' file
ABC A BBBBB0
ABC A BBBBB1
ABC A BBBBB2
ABC A BBBBB3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/<h2 id="title">\s*(.*\S)\s*<\/h2>/\1/p' file
```

Use pattern matching to return the required strings.

N.B. `\s` matches white space and `\S` is its dual. Thus `(.*\S)` captures word or words.